# Refer to varbales as a object passed in function

Tags: javascript

The issue.
I need to create a global function called

> layerdiable(layer);

In many instances this funciton will be  like...

> layerdiable(heatmap_tree);
>   layerdiable(heatmap_house);
>   layerdiable(heatmap_person);

each of the above have varables related

> var heatmap_tree = false;
>   var heatmap_house = false;

and so on
What I want to do is basicly....

> function distroylayer(layer){
>   layer =! layer;
>   }

( wich i would want to realy work like.... )

> function distroylayer(heatmap_tree ){
>   heatmap_tree !=heatmap_tree ;
>   }

Making heatmap_tree  the opposite of its current value... ( which should be false... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Primitives such as booleans are passed by value, not by reference.

But you don't need a function for this. All you need is:

```
somevar = !somevar;
```

This will toggle `somevar` between true and false.

Comment: That was a mistype,  actually had that.  in the function i want to call.  However I would be able to just do this anyway in he insight.  as the Js on the creation page is done via PHP.   onclick="'.$layer.'= !'.$layer.'; lam(); "

Comment: Stack overflow.  Poking tired programmers in the ass since... **inserts creation date**

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to global variables as `window` object members:

```
function disableLayer(layer) {
    window[layer] = !window[layer];
}

disableLayber('heatmap_tree');
```